# LinkedList: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list, heap-memory

I'm trying to make a graph implementation for an assignment, which has Graph(GraphImp) objects and Node(NodeImp) objects.

Node objects contain a reference to their Graph, x & y co-ordinates and a name.

The Graph object contains a linked list of its Nodes.

The problem occurs when I try to add a Node into the middle of the List of Nodes (Appending to the end works fine). The program runs out of heap space. I'm not sure why this is occurring though, since the complexity of inserting to a LinkedList should be O(1), and Java (I believe) uses pointers, rather that the objects themselves. I've also tried an arraylist

Making the heap larger is not an option in this instance, and (as far as I understand) should not be the source of the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.LinkedList.addBefore(LinkedList.java:795)
    at java.util.LinkedList.add(LinkedList.java:361)
    at pt.graph.GraphImp.addNode(GraphImp.java:79)
    at pt.graph.NodeImp.<init>(NodeImp.java:25)
    at pt.graph.Graphs.newNode(Solution.java:68)
```

Here is the Code:

```
class Graphs
{

    static Node newNode(Graph g, double xpos, double ypos, String name) throws InvalidGraphException,InvalidLabelException
    {
        if(g==null || !(g instanceof GraphImp)){   //Checking validity of inputs
            throw new InvalidGraphException();
        }
        if(name==null){
            throw new InvalidLabelException();
        }

        NodeImp[] existNodes = ((GraphImp)g).getNodes(); //Get all Nodes already present in the Graph
        for(int i=0;i<existNodes.length;i++){
            if(existNodes[i].getXPos() == xpos && existNodes[i].getYPos() == ypos){ //If node already present at this position, throw InvalidLabelException()
                throw new InvalidLabelException();
            }
        }

        Node n = new NodeImp((GraphImp)g, xpos, ypos, name); //If all inputs are valid, create new node

        return n;
    }

}

class NodeImp extends Node //Node Class
{

    private Object flags = null;
    private GraphImp g = null;
    private double xpos = 0.0;
    private double ypos = 0.0;
    private String name = "";

    NodeImp(GraphImp g, double xpos, double ypos, String name){
        this.g = g;
        this.xpos = xpos;
        this.ypos = ypos;
        this.name = name;
        g.addNode(this); // Add Node to the Graph
    }
}

class GraphImp extends Graph
{
    private LinkedList<NodeImp> nodes = new LinkedList<NodeImp>(); //LinkedList of all Nodes in the Graph

    GraphImp(){

    }

    NodeImp[] getNodes(){ //Returns an array of all Nodes
        NodeImp[] nArr = new NodeImp[nodes.size()];
        return nodes.toArray(nArr);
    }

    int countNodes(){ //Returns number of Nodes
        return nodes.size();
    }

    void addNode(NodeImp n){ //Add a Node to the LinkedList in order
        boolean added = false;
        for(int i = 0;i<nodes.size();i++){
            if(n.compareTo(nodes.get(i))<=0 ){
                nodes.add(i,n);         //fails here
            }
        }
        if(!added){
            nodes.add(n);
        }
        return;
    }

}
```

Comment: There is no explicit concept of pointers in Java. Everything are objects.

Comment: where is the code for Node class ?

Comment: @noMAD: Yes and no. Variables are all *references* to objects, not objects themselves. References behave similarly (but not identically) to pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not exiting your loop after inserting the new node in the middle of the list. Your code will try to insert the same node an infinite number of times, hence the OOM.

Try this:

```
for(int i = 0;i<nodes.size();i++){
    if(n.compareTo(nodes.get(i))<=0 ){
        nodes.add(i,n);
        added = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

As an aside, your insertion is pretty inefficient. Since you know the list is already sorted you could use a binary search to find the insertion point rather than an O(n) scan of the list. Your current implementation is O(n^2) to insert n items, but it could be O(n log n).

Comment: Cameron - your points are excellent.  Can you mention though why you think he would be adding an infinite number of times?  Won't it be added at most size times?

Comment: It's because you add a node at position `i`, moving the current node (let's call it 'x') at that position to `i+1`. The loop then continues, and checks the new node against `i+1` which is `x`again. `x` now moves to `i+2` and the list now has two copies of the new node, at `i` and `i+1`. This repeats forever.

Comment: Hey Amir, It's infinite because the size of the List increases by 1 each iteration, thus unless it breaks, it will never reach the end of the list (what a derpy fail of me)

Comment: @CameronSkinner Binary search on a linked list cannot provide O(log(n)) runtime, so I do not see how using binary search would be applicable in this case. For a linked list, accessing the middle element (which is the first step of a binary search algorithm) is an O(n) operation.

You are right however that the efficiency can be improved. Calling get(i) in a loop is rather inefficient for a linked list. It is better to use an [iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSequentialList.html#iterator()) to loop through the list.

Comment: @CameronSkinner: If the list is always sorted, wouldn't it be worth considering using a `Set<NodeImp>` instead?

Comment: @Alderath: Yes, you're right, random access into a LinkedList is inefficient. I assumed that it would be OK to use an ArrayList or some other form of random access list.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to diagnose the exact cause of your `OOM` without the whole program, but here's one observation:

`getNodes()`

is pretty inefficient.  You `toArray` the `LinkedList` simply to traverse it and look for a particular instance.  Why not just use .`contains()` properly?  No need to copy all of the elements then.  Or just do what you were doing before but do it on the `List` instead of an array copy:

```
 for(NodeImp n : existingNodes){
     if(n.getXPos() == xpos && n.getYPos() == ypos){
         throw new InvalidLabelException();
     }
 }
```

My guess is that the 'old' approach of adding to the end was likely to hit an OOM as well but for some heisenbug reason it hasn't manifested itself.  Have you run with a profiler?

Comment: Thanks for the efficiency suggestion Amir - always appreciated.